# WPF - Catel - Disable CommandManager for Window in different Thread

Tags: wpf, multithreading, catel

Because the `PleaseWaitService` was removed with Catel 5.0.0, I copied the sourcecode of the implementation out of version 4.5.0 in an separate lib and linked the "new" lib and used the Service like before.
But because there were some errors with the `PleaseWaitService` in combination with our existing codebase I rewrote and simpliefied the Service (just supporting WPF).

Now I'm showing the `PleaseWaitWindow` in a different Thread which works in my testproject but not in production. I'm getting an `InvalidOperationException` when I call `window.Show()` (the window was created in the same thread).

In the exception's stacktrace are some calls from the Catel CommandManager

`at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess()
at Catel.MVVM.CommandManager.SubscribeToKeyboardEvents(FrameworkElement view) in C:\CI_WS\Ws\107901\Source\Catel\src\Catel.MVVM\Catel.MVVM.Shared\MVVM\Commands\CommandManager.wpf.cs:line 64
at Catel.MVVM.CommandManager.OnWindowLoaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in C:\CI_WS\Ws\107901\Source\Catel\src\Catel.MVVM\Catel.MVVM.Shared\MVVM\Commands\CommandManager.wpf.cs:line 78
[...]
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)`

I have registered one Command in the CommandManager which won't be used in my custom PleaseWaitWindow.

So my question is: How can I disable the standard injection from the Commandmanager into the window?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of Catel is that everything is pluggable. If you want different behavior for the command manager, you can create your own version and override the things you want differently. Don't forget to register it in the `ServiceLocator`.

Comment: I asked because I didn't want to copy your code and just change one line. But I did as you intended and just changed the if-statement
```if (app != null) { ... }``` to ```if (app != null && app.Dispatcher == Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher) { ... }```
Should I commit this and create a pull request to change this in the existing codebase?

Comment: I think that's actually a good idea. Please create an issue & PR and we'll make sure it gets merged. On 2nd thought, I will add this myself in the current beta branch so it will be added to the next release.